# Format an ISO8601 datetime with nanosecond precision as d-m-Y H:i:s

Tags: php, datetime

I'm getting dates from a feed in this format:

```
2016-06-03T08:17:25.819350100Z
```

I'm trying to format it using `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, but I get an error saying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on
> boolean in /opt/lampp/htdocs/entim/xml/index2.php:40 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/entim/xml/index2.php on line 40

Here is my code:

```
$dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ATOM, '2016-06-03T08:17:25.819350100Z');
$formattedDate = $dto->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
echo $formattedDate;
```

Error:

> Failed to parse time string (2016-06-03T08:17:25.819350100Z) at
> position 0 (2): The timezone could not be found in the database

I also tried:

```
$d = new DateTime('2016-06-03T08:17:25.819350100Z');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

But this gives:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2016-06-03T08:17:25.819350100Z) at position 0 (2): The timezone could not be found in the database in /in/2b16j:3

Comment: This is a report from the server, I have it in a xml file.

Comment: This is a correctly-formatted ISO8601 date. Unfortunately, PHP is unable to correctly parse it when fractional seconds are used with this much precision: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51950

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cut the string, but it's a hack

```
$dto = new DateTime(substr('2016-06-03T08:17:25.819350100Z', 0, 26) . 'Z');
echo $dto->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing [this bug #51950](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51950) - it would work if you strip decimal fraction part (or PHP fix the bug):

```
php > $dto = \DateTime::createFromFormat(\DateTime::ATOM, '2016-06-03T08:17:25Z');
php > var_dump($dto);
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2016-06-03 08:17:25.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

First exception is caused by `DateTime::createFromFormat` returning `false` if parsing wasn't successful (you should check it anyway).

Comment: The sample datetime input used in this answer does not reflect the precision in the question.  Changing the input to avoid the failure (and not showing how) is not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

This fatal parsing error no longer occurs once you upgrade to PHP8.

Fortunately for you, preserving the decimal value of seconds is not needed. For clarity, I'll explain that that the nanosecond precision will be truncated to microsecond precision by the DateTime constructor.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5H8a9))

```
$dt = '2016-06-03T08:17:25.819350100Z';
echo (new DateTime($dt))->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
// 03-06-2016 08:17:25
```

I am wrapping the new DateTime instantiation in parentheses to avoid making a variable declaration.